# Javascript errors on lines that don't exist

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error

My app uses AJAX to report all Javascript errors that my users get. Occasionally, there are errors on lines that don't exist. Is there any kind of hint as to what this could be?

For example:

> Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null (/mysite/ on line 11823)
>   Script: /mysite/
>   Line:11823
>   User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4

The source file it's referring to is an HTML page that doesn't even have any Javascript in it other than a `$(document).ready()`. All other JS is included through a script tag.

I'm not entirely sure where that line is even coming from. I don't have 12k lines of JS total. I have one minified 'all.js' file which is 9k lines.

Comment: "of null". there's probably some dynamically generated code blocks somewhere, one of which does have 11800+ lines.

Comment: Look in the console. (Fx or Chrome)  Click on the link to the error

Comment: `/mysite/ on line 11823` - from this I can tell that it happens possibly in code block which is located directly in body of a document, located somewhere at the and of a page. And line number is such a huge because of lines of HTML before that script.

Comment: I did, just commenting on a tangent.